# Not throwing exception when object is null

Tags: c#, class, collections, stack

So I created a basic stack which takes in a string and gets passed in an object. I want to make sure that if the object being passed in is null, it throws an exception. However when I pass in a null object, the exception doesn't get thrown and can't see why.

```
public class Stack
{
    public readonly Stack<string> foodStack = new Stack<string>();
    public void Push(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You cannot add null to the stack");
        }

        string foodObject = obj.ToString();
        foodStack.Push(foodObject);
    }
```

Main Method:

```
Stack item1 = new Stack();
item1.Push(null);
```

I have tried changing the type of exception.

Comment: Are you sure you instantiate your `Stack` and not [System.Collections.Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods Yes I am sure, I even changed the class name but still same issue

Comment: Side note: better `throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj), "You cannot add null to the stack");` - let's be exact when complaining (`InvalidOerationException` vs. `ArgumentNullException`)

Comment: Side note: `obj is null` is a slightly better choice instead of `obj == null`, since arbitrary object can implement custom `==` operator and return `false` on `== null`

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zBgf4E) with the code you have shown, so the problem must lie in the code you didn't show.

Comment: What happens when you debug it line by line?

Answer (score 1):

What's your environment/target?

```
// .NET FW 4.8, C# 5.0
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace NsCustomStack {
    public class Astack {
        public readonly Stack<string> foodStack = new Stack<string>();
        public void Push(object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("You cannot add null to the stack");
            }
            string foodObject = obj.ToString();
            foodStack.Push(foodObject);
        }
    }
    class CustomStack {
        static void Main() {
            Astack item1 = new Astack(); item1.Push(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: You cannot add null to the stack

___ at NsCustomStack.Astack.Push(Object obj)

___ at NsCustomStack.CustomStack.Main()

**UPD** My guess is

```
Stack item1 = new Stack();
item1.Push(null);
```

uses System.Collections.Stack which Push method accepts null.

**The solution can be to use the fully qualified name for your custom Stack:**

```
var item1 = new YourNamespace.Stack();
item1.Push(null);
```

I simulated the issue with this code:

```
using System.Collections;
namespace ConsoleApp3Classes {
    public class Stack {
        public readonly Stack<string> foodStack = new Stack<string>();
        public void Push(object obj) {
            if (obj is null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj), "You cannot add null to the stack");
            }
            string foodObject = obj.ToString();
            foodStack.Push(foodObject);
        }
    }
}
namespace ConsoleApp3 {
    internal class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var item1 = new Stack(); item1.Push(null);
            var item1a = new ConsoleApp3Classes.Stack(); item1a.Push(null);
        }
    }
}
```

"var item1 = new Stack(); item1.Push(null);" doesn't generate the exception while the next line does.

Comment: So, basically your answer is "cannot reproduce"?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods Provided a solution